# Adding new Members to an Array and Creating/Updating the Referenced Documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

i have the following code:

```
function() {

  Server.findOne({
      _id: id
    })
    .populate('_players')
    .exec(function(err, server) {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      } else if (server) {
        console.log('Server: ' + server.name);
        for (elem in allPlayers) {
          if (allPlayers.hasOwnProperty(elem)) {
            //console.log('DEBUG: allPlayers has Property');
            var player = allPlayers[elem];

            var obj = server._players.find(function(obj) {
              return obj.steam_id === player.steamID;
            });
            if (obj) {
              console.log('|| ' + obj.name + ' was online at: ' + obj.last_online);
              console.log('-->                 update to: ' + new Date());
              obj.last_online = new Date();
              obj.save(function(err, obj) {
                if (err) return console.log(err);
                console.log('DEBUG: existing Player safed: ', obj.name);
              })
            } else {
              var newPlayer = new Player();
              newPlayer._id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
              newPlayer.name = player.name;
              newPlayer.steam_id = player.steamID;
              newPlayer.last_online = new Date();

              newPlayer.save(function(err, newPlayer) {
                if (err) return console.log(err);
                console.log('DEBUG: newPlayer safed: ', newPlayer.name);
              });

              server._players.push(newPlayer);
            }

          } else {
            console.log('There is no Property (allPlayers)');
          }
        }

        server.save(function(err, server) {
          if (err) return console.log(err);
          console.log('DEBUG: server safed: ', server.name);
        })
      } else {
        console.log('There is no such server (updatePlayers)');
      }
    })
}
```

So what this does is getting all existing players which belong to a specific server. If there are new players in the allPlayers array they shall be saved in the database. If the players already are existing, the last_online time is just getting updated. Its basically working as it should besides of one issue. If I try to update the existing players from the database, the server is safed BEFORE the existing players are saved. So they are actually not been updated because of this and I absolutely do not understand why this is. New players are safed correctly btw...

Would love to get any advise!

// Debug output is like this:

```
{
    > DEBUG: server safed:  TestServer
    DEBUG: existing Player safed:  How's it going
    DEBUG: existing Player safed:  skullsoul2
    DEBUG: existing Player safed:  Terra
    DEBUG: existing Player safed:  Rundas
    DEBUG: existing Player safed:  [OG]GreyForce
    DEBUG: existing Player safed:  Thyrenos

}
```

// but should be like this

```
{
    DEBUG: existing Player safed:  How's it going
    DEBUG: existing Player safed:  skullsoul2
    DEBUG: existing Player safed:  Terra
    DEBUG: existing Player safed:  Rundas
    DEBUG: existing Player safed:  [OG]GreyForce
    DEBUG: existing Player safed:  Thyrenos
    > DEBUG: server safed:  TestServer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a **lot** of improvements here. One big thing in consideration is that you are dealing with "async" methods here which are basically going to act on a "callback" or a "Promise" which will be resolved where execution is complete.

### Using Promise.all for resolution of "many" updates

```js
function updateServerPlayers(id,allPlayers,callback) {

  // Get an array of steamID to use in the query to .populate()
  var steamIds = allPlayers.map(function(player) {
    return player.steamID;
  })

  /*
    findById is pretty much to the point

    Also want to remove any players not present in allPlayers from the array
    response. This makes comparison easy.
  */

  Server.findById(id).populate({
    "path": "_players",
    "match": {
        "steam_id": { "$in": steamIds }
    }
  }).exec(function(err,server) {
    if (err) { 
      callback(err);     // should handle the err in the callback response
    } else if (server) {
      // Actually working on the object here

      var lastOnline = new Date();

      var updatePlayers = _players.map(function(player){ return player.steam_id });
      var allUpdates = allPlayers.filter(function(player) {
        return updatePlayers.indexOf(player.steamID) == -1
      }).map(function(player) {
        /* 
          Make an .update() request for all players not present on the server
          using the "upsert" option to create them if not found
        */
        return Player.update(
          { "steam_id": player.steamID },
          {
            "$setOnInsert": {
              "name": player.name,
            },
            "$set": { "last_online": lastOnline }
          },
          { "upsert": true }
        )
      })

      /* 
        Updating existing server players in one operation
        but appending to the list of allUpdates
      */
      allUpdates.push(
        Player.update(
          { "steam_id": { "$in": updatePlayers } },
          { "$set": { "last_online": lastOnline } },
          { "multi": true }
        )
      );

      // This is where we actually resolve things
      Promise.all(allUpdates).then(function(responses) {

        // Just get the upsert responses
        var upserted = [];
        responses.filter(function(response) {
          return res.hasOwnProperty("upserted");
        }).forEach(function(response) {
          upserted = upserted.concat(response.upserted);
        });

        // Then filter back to just the _id values
        upserted = upserted.map(function(upsert) {
          return upsert._id;
        });

        // Then "atomically" add to the server array with $addToSet
        Server.update(
          { "_id": id },
          { "$addToSet": { "_players": upserted } },
          callback
        );

      }).catch(callback);   // return any error

    } else {
      // Not found should still be an error response
      callback(new Error("server not found"))
    }
  });

}
```

The basic logic you are looking for asks these things:

1. Get the data for the current `Server` and we really just **need** to know which members of `allPlayers` are already in the `_players` array. The `.populate()` is altered here to "just" return those matches and no other data that is **not** contained in `allPlayers`. Useful to know for both the `"last_online"` only update as well as determining possible `allPlayers` to create, where the latter will be the difference between the lists.
2. Once you know which members of `allPlayers` are already in `_players` and those that are not, you can break this down into two classes of update. Being:

   - Updates that "may" need to "create" a new `Player` if one does not exist. These are individual lookups to "upsert" where the `"steam_id"` is not found.
   - Updates that can just be applied to existing players to simply update the `"last_online"` value. These a "bulk" modifications that can be made to **all** listed documents to `$in` with a single request.
3. With "all" the requests ( many upserts, and "one" multi update ) constructed in an array of "Promises", you resolve them with `Promise.all()` and return the data from the modification. The complete set of modification responses well tell you the `_id` values of "upserted" documents for `Player` and therefore which ones need to be added to the `_players` array.
4. Once you know which ones to add, you can "safely" apply this to the `Server` document using `$addToSet`. This will **only** add new `_id` members referencing each `Player` "if" that value is not already present. It should not be there according to the logic, but `$addToSet` ensures no "duplicate" data in the case where something else might have already added to the `_players` array on that document.

### Using "Bulk" operations of MongoDB to update "many" at once

```js
function updateServerPlayers(id,allPlayers,callback) {

  // Get an array of steamID to use in the query to .populate()
  var steamIds = allPlayers.map(function(player) {
    return player.steamID;
  })

  /*
    findById is pretty much to the point

    Also want to remove any players not present in allPlayers from the array
    response. This makes comparison easy.
  */

  Server.findById(id).populate({
    "path": "_players",
    "match": {
        "steam_id": { "$in": steamIds }
    }
  }).exec(function(err,server) {
    if (err) { 
      callback(err);     // should handle the err in the callback response
    } else if (server) {
      // Actually working on the object here

      var bulk = Player.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

      var updatePlayers = _players.map(function(player){ return player.steam_id });

      // Build the operations for possible upsert
      allPlayers.filter(function(player) {
        return updatePlayers.indexOf(player.steamID) == -1
      }).forEach(function(player) {
        bulk.find({ "steam_id": player.steamID }).upsert().updateOne({
          "$setOnInsert": { "name": player.name },
          "$currentDate": { "last_online": true }
        });
      });

      // Append the operation for 
      bulk.find({ "steam_id": { "$in": updatePlayers } }).update({
        "$currentDate": { "last_online": true }
      });

      bulk.execute(function(err,result) {
        if (err) callback(err);

        // Get only the "cast" ObjectId values that were upserted
        var upserted = result.getUpSertedIds().map(function(upsert) {
          return mongoose.Types.ObjectId( upsert._id.valueOf() )
        })

        // Atomically update the server object with $addToSet
        Server.update(
          { "_id": id },
          { "$addToSet": { "_players": upserted } },
          callback
        );
      });
    } else {
      callback(new Error("server not found"))
    }
  });

}
```

This uses very much the same process with the exception that whilst the previous listing creates an "array of promises" to apply to the server, this form "builds" a **single request** that actually sends all the operations to the server at once. Since there is also **one response**, there is no need to wait for each request to complete since it was only one request to begin with. This provides **huge** performance gains.

The same case is true that the "single response" contains all of the "upserted" `_id` values for any `Player` that was created. This can then be used with the same `$addToSet` operation to append them to the `_players` array.

This is a much better approach to use, but it does come with a catch. Since the "bulk" operations are using the methods from the underlying driver "directly", there are not the same safeguards on database connection as is present in all the mongoose model methods.

In practice this means that either a "mongoose method" ( such as the `.findById()` call on the model ) **must** have executed first in order for the underlying driver method references to resolve to the correct object, or you otherwise need to take other steps to ensure the connection is made. By the listing, this is exactly the case here since `.findById()` is already called.

So though mongoose "hides" that complexity of connecting deliberately, it's generally "good practice" to include a "wrapper" around your application initialization that "ensures" the database is connected before the rest of the application runs.

Where you need this is it best to set up this event handler as follows:

```js
mongoose.connection.on("once",function() {
    // Init application in here
});
```

But with the structure of this code it is not required.

---

The other main thing here is that the "whole" process "should" be wrapped in a function that is either going to return a `callback` or a `Promise` as is demonstrated.

All actions within are "async" methods, so there is nothing here you can just `return` a result from as the "async" calls need to resolve before there is in fact any result to give. So you should "always" wrap things that use such "async" methods in one of those ways, pass in the arguments and then deal with the response in the "resolver" function. Not as a `return`.

This may take a while to digest, but it is worth it to understand the principles and use them futher. The results, even in the first listing case, will do what you want and also run a lot faster and more efficiently.

Plus, the code itself is a lot cleaner by taking a straightforward approach.

Comment: Wow. First of all: Thank you so much! As you of course already noticed Im pretty new to Mongoose/MongoDB as well as to Node. As you already noticed this is hard to digest and I propably have to read this a couple of times more to understand completely (at least because Im German :D ) but this already helped me alot! Thank you for your time!!